# Aggregating table data - grouping sets? other?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to aggregate multiple columns for a report without running multiple selects.
It's a bit column, and I wanted to display 2 rows (a yes row, and a no row) for each column.
Desired result is this:

```
    |Alimony |Married |HasCustody
Yes |3       |2       |4
No  |2       |3       |1
```

I tried to do SUM(Cast IsPayingAlimony as tinyint).  I looked at pivot, unpivot, cube, rollup.  I think the closest I've come is group by grouping sets.  But even with grouping sets, I can't get to the two rows.
Here is my sql:

```
CREATE TABLE ClientStatus
(  ClientID INT NOT NULL,
   IsPayingAlimony BIT NOT NULL,
   IsMarried BIT NOT NULL,
   HasCustody BIT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Status] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
   (
    [ClientID] ASC
   )
)
;
INSERT INTO ClientStatus
(ClientID, IsPayingAlimony, IsMarried, HasCustody)
VALUES (1,0,0,0)
      ,(2,1,1,1)
      ,(3,1,0,1)
      ,(4,0,1,1)
      ,(5,1,0,1) 
;

SELECT * FROM ClientStatus
```

Here is the group by grouping sets query.

```
SELECT IsPayingAlimony, IsMarried, HasCustody, COUNT(*) AS Records
 FROM ClientStatus
GROUP BY Grouping Sets ((IsPayingAlimony), (IsMarried), (HasCustody))
```

And here are the results.    I'm afraid I'm over-thinking (under-thinking?!) this, but I don't know how to get this down to the 2 rows.

```
IsPayingAlimony |IsMarried |HasCustody |Records
NULL            |NULL      |0          |1
NULL            |NULL      |1          |4
NULL            |0         |NULL       |3
NULL            |1         |NULL       |2
0               |NULL      |NULL       |2
1               |NULL      |NULL       |3
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking `values()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    v.descr,
    sum(case when cs.IsPayingAlimony = v.val then 1 else 0 end) alimony,
    sum(case when cs.IsMarried       = v.val then 1 else 0 end) married,
    sum(case when cs.HasCustody      = v.val then 1 else 0 end) has_custody
from ClientStatus cs
cross join (values (1, 'Yes'), (0, 'No')) v(val, descr)
group by v.descr
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f6e4d06c4c9e3f99e71a1a01f8feab7f)**:

```
descr | alimony | married | has_custody
:---- | ------: | ------: | ----------:
No    |       2 |       3 |           1
Yes   |       3 |       2 |           4
```

Comment: That does it!.  I will have to do a little extra manipulation for some nulls that I've uncovered, but otherwise this gives me exactly what I need.  I cannot upvote because I do not have enough reputation points.  Thank you so much for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I was nearly done with this when the other answer was posted, got distracted, just a slightly different way to approach it:

```
;WITH poss(yn, oo) AS (SELECT 'Yes',1 UNION ALL SELECT 'No',0)
SELECT poss.yn, 
  Alimony = SUM(CASE cs.IsPayingAlimony WHEN poss.oo THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  Married = SUM(CASE cs.IsMarried       WHEN poss.oo THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  Custody = SUM(CASE cs.HasCustody      WHEN poss.oo THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM poss CROSS JOIN dbo.ClientStatus AS cs
GROUP BY poss.yn;
```

Comment: This works, too.  GMB get the checkmark since he was just a little bit faster to post.  Both yours and his answers are clear and concise.  Thanks for your response!